# Maximum force in tug of war

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, friction, string

In tug of war,
The maximum force that a person can exert on the rope depends on the static coefficient of friction.
Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is correct, contrary to what a lot of people first think, it's not kinetic friction but static friction with the ground that allows you to win a tug of war. If you weigh more, the maximum static friction increases and you have an advantage; if gravity is greater where you are than where your opponent is (IDK how, but lets just assume) you have an advantage; and if the surface you are standing on has a greater coefficient of static friction than the one he is standing on, once again you have an advantage. Here's why:

Static friction is any force between two touching objects in which neither of the objects moves relative to one another. You need static friction with the ground in order to pull the rope in your direction: I know, it might sound a little weird because the term has "static" in it, and to win the tug of war you need to move, but just bear with me.

For now, let's say instead of winning the tug of war, your goal is simply to resist the force of your opponent; that is, to keep still. He pulls on the rope, but you don't move; your feet's static friction with the ground keep you in place. He pulls harder, and harder, and eventually, the force he imparts is greater than the maximum force of static friction contact between your feet and the ground can impart back on him, and you begin to slide in his direction (now there's kinetic friction, and he's winning the tug of war).

He beats you this time, but you guys decide to play again. However, you, not wanting to lose again, decide to do anything to win, and you stuff your pockets with really heavy rocks. By doing this you have increased your weight, therefore the normal force the ground exerts back on you, and therefore the magnitude of the maximum static friction the ground can provide to resist your opponent's tug (the maximum static friction is proportional to the normal force between the two objects touching). He can no longer move you since the maximum force of static friction between your feet and the ground is now so great.

Now, you decide to try to pull him. In order to pull him backward, you must lift one of your feet and place it behind the other. Here is where a lot of times the confusion happens because since you are moving, people think its kinetic friction that helps you pull. But while you do this, the other foot, the one that you didn't lift, must remain in place, and not slide in his direction: hence, once again it is static friction keeping it in place, and not kinetic. Only if you slid while moving your feet back would there be kinetic friction, and sliding is not the way to win a tug of war.

[image: tug of war]